# jqGRId - Can we have grouptext to be dynamic

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

While grouping , the group text appears to be Name or title of column we use ..

Can we use another column value to be group text?

Answer (score 0):

We cant used another column name to be group text

But we can play around using loadComplete function and modify group text by looping through the table